# Breakdown of large dataset for Power BI

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I have started to build a Power BI dashboard to display various information about a lot of customers.

All my information is stored in a MS SQL Server database, and my main table has 30+ million rows (increasing once every month by ~1 mil rows). Data is a mix between financials and dimensions type information.

Before I have created a monthly report in PowerPoint, but I want to create more flexibility and have therefore started to build the same “setup” in Power BI.

My issue is that performance is relatively slow; which I think it shouldn’t be, especially if I am to distribute to senior stakeholders in my company. Ideally I would like the numbers to “appear” in an instant, rather than having to wait 10, 15, 30 or 60 seconds for things to load every time you change a filter.
Currently I am using DirectQuery.

I have now experimented with creating a bunch of aggregated tables on my database, so that I lose a ton of details, but am able to load data much much faster (even with direct query), almost instant. My idea is to create a stored procedure that fires once a month when new data is loaded, to update each of these aggregated tables with newest data.

However I feel like it kind of defeats the purpose of having a BI tool, as I lose ability to  drill down and do ad hoc investigations into underlying parameters of each metric etc.
I have created some relationships in Power BI that gives me some drill functionality, but not nearly as detailed as I would like.

What is best practice in relation to this? Is it common to do aggregated tables, even if it is on the expense of doing drill downs and losing detail? Or should I consider some other approach?

I have other datasets with even more detail (100s of million of rows), so looking for best practice for when I get around to these more detailed datasets.

Comment: Try to stop using Direct Query, 100s of million of rows is not too much for properly designed PowerBI/SSAS database.

Comment: Why do you say your data is too large to import into Power BI? Have you tested and validated the size and performance in Power BI Desktop? As an example, the most recent model I worked on had 4x fact tables of 50M, 100M, 120M and 180M rows. It works just fine in Power BI Desktop. That model is hosted on a PBI Premium capacity. The general best practice is to import detail rows to the PBI data model.

Comment: Currently it is not hosted on a server, rather the pbix file is shared between the few users we are on a network drive. I am trying to keep the file size small so that people don’t need to download a few GB’s every time they need to work in it. But perhaps when we get the server version it makes sense to just import all the data directly into the report?

Comment: A 30M row fact table shouldn't be anywhere close to a few GBs when compressed in a pbix. If you've got an enormous, wide table, you should look at dimensionalizing. Again, have you tested an import to determine the size of the import model?

Comment: I will try that out when I get into office tomorrow morning. Thanks.

Comment: I can see that my dataset on the server is approximately 35 GB. I am in the process of importing it into Power BI, however it has been loading for more than 1 hr and is just half way done. My concern is how long it will take on my larger datasets with many many more rows?

Comment: Final file size 3.1 GB

Comment: You have a 30M row dataset that is 35GB? What are you storing in those rows? That's more than 1MB/row, which is huge. Can you remove some of those columns? Are there any large text or binary fields you're not using for analysis? For reference, the model I mentioned above with 4x fact tables of 50M, 100M, 120M and 180M rows is only 3.4GB on disk after loading, and I am doing several things that I **know** are making it gigabytes larger than it would otherwise be.

Comment: Wouldn’t that be 1 kB/row ish? I don’t have complete control over the data (I control the database, but I source it from somewhere else, so I need to keep their data types to some degree). All my text fields are nvarchar’s with a max length approximately the same as the longest text in that column. But I am under the impression that nvarchars don’t take up more space than what you put in them (as opposed to char?)

Comment: I have 85 columns, but can cut away approximately half, but it only cut my final file to 2/3rds

Comment: Can you use the aggregation mode? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-aggregations, Or move the tables to a Clustered Column Store Index?